# Remove border in visualforce page added in Lightning Page

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

Using the lightning page editor is possible add visualforce pages in a lightning page but that add a border and I want to remove it
[image]

Comment: You should always add [try catch](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling) in your controller code and display error message in page in user friendly manner.

Comment: I used a page as example, the error isn't relevant.

Comment: Gotcha, bad example for this question ;) I don't think we can reduce the space, its because to match with layout. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Is there a tabindex on the element? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154933/remove-blue-border-on-lightning-component-within-vf-page-created-using-ltngouta

Comment: I changed the image to be more clear ;) I think the same but I want to remove it because the lightning components don't add the border.

Comment: i have similar problem, but in my case the border occupy ~50% of the space... :( if there is any suggestion it may help